# Rails: to_json method not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm a bit stumped on this. I have a User model. I am trying to convert instances to JSON format. However, it's not returning what I expect:

```
> u = User.first
> u.to_json
=> "\"#<User:0x104ac7718>\""
```

Instead of returning a hash of the object's attributes, `to_json` is returning just a string with the name of the model. Any ideas?

Comment: What `User.first` return?  Did you tried `require 'json'` before `u.to_json` ?

Comment: I'm with @konus here, do a rails console session and ask for User.first and see what you get back.

Comment: This is what I get when I do User.first `=> #<User id: 1, email: "no@one.com",  created_at: "2011-04-22 20:36:57", updated_at: "2011-04-29 18:22:28">`

Comment: @Chanpory what does it tell you when you say User.first.to_json.class  ? Mine comes back String and appears to show a hash of returned json just fine. Also what ruby version?

Comment: It looks like it had to do with some gems being out of date. I ran a gem update, and now it seems to be working!