# to_json is returning empty object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a ruby class with the following definition:

```
class MyResponse
        attr_writer :status, :message

        def initialize(status,message) 
                @status = status
                @message = message
        end
end
```

When I try to do a to_json on the object of type MyResponse, I am properly getting the json converted string.

The problem is, with the same set of parameters passed to MyResponse, I'm getting empty string sometimes.

Ex:

```
response = MyRespons.new("Abcd", 0)
```

puts response.to_json gives:

```
"{\"status\": \"Abcd\", \"message\": 0}"
```

The same sometimes gives:

```
"\"#<MyResponse:0xb687d884>\""
```

My question is how do i catch the json errors? Because, in the second case, there is absolutely no difference in the parameters passed to MyResponse class.

The behaviour is random.

Update: I found a similar question. But the answer is to update the gem. I cannot update my current gem.
[Rails: to_json method not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836537/rails-to-json-method-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, turns out that the json gem had an issue. I now am using an alias to the original to_json which seems to be working fine.